# Range sum using regex

Tags: regex, google-sheets, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet with data as follows:

```
    |A    |B       |C       |D       |
+---+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|1  |Day  |Result 1|Result 2|Result 3|
+---+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|2  |Feb 1|A10-2   |B10-5   |B10-9   |
+---+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|3  |Feb 2|A10-9   |A10-9   |        |
+---+-----+--------+--------+--------+
|4  |Feb 3|B10-8   |A10-2   |B10-7   |
```

I want to get the sum of the second digit in each cell, in two totals based on the first letter. In other words, I want a sum of the second digit where the first letter is `A`, and a sum of the second digit where the first letter is `B`.

So, for `A` I am expecting to get `22` (2+9+9+2), and for `B` I am expecting to get `29` (5+9+8+7).

I have used `REGEXEXTRACT` to get the second digit, for example:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2,"A10-(\d+)")
```

this gives me `2`. However, if I try:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(B2:D4,"A10-(\d+)")
```

to check all cells, I get *an array value could not be found* and I'm not sure what else to try.

Pseudocode for what I want would be something like:

```
=SUM(REGEXEXTRACT(B2:D4,"A10-(\d+)"))
```

but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put `A` and `B` somewhere (say in E2 and E3) then enter and copy down:

```
=sum(ArrayFormula(value(right(B$2:D$4))*--ArrayFormula(left(B$2:D$4)=E2)))
```

Presumably could be simplified but requirement seems to be too specialised to be worth much bother.